# scipy minimize ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am trying to optimize the following function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
def test(var,q,pts):
    eMin,eMax=var*(1-(1./q)**.5)**2,var*(1+(1./q)**.5)**2
    eVal=np.linspace(eMin,eMax,pts) # create space of eigenvalues
    pdf=q/(2*np.pi*var*eVal)*((eMax-eVal)*(eVal-eMin))**.5 # MP pdf based on eigenvalue space
    pdf=pd.Series(pdf,index=eVal)
    return pdf.sum()
```

The function works well: try in fact

```
test(0.5, 10, 1000)
```

But  when I try to optimize it with scipy minimize:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
minimize(test, 0.5, (10,1000))
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Index data must be 1-dimensional
```

which in my understanding refers to the last line, i.e. `pdf=pd.Series(pdf, index=eVal)`. However, I don't understand what is the problem here as the function works fine outside the optimization process.

Comment: Apart from your error, `scipy.optimize.minimize` expects a function that returns a **scalar** value. Your `test` function returns a `pd.Series` with 1000 entries, so it's still not really clear what you want to minimize.

Comment: Right, I had forgot to add the ```.sum()``` at the end. Essentially, I need to minimize the resulting sum of the series ```pdf```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the `eVal` variable which is a 2D `np.ndarray` because `var` is passed as a 1D `np.ndarray` (for e.g., `[0.5]`) to the `test` function when `minimize` is used. Due to this, `eMin` and `eMax` are also 1D arrays and you end up getting `eVal` as a 2D `np.ndarray`. Index argument in `pd.Series` must be 1D. Therefore, you must flatten your `eVal` to 1D as follows:

```python
eVal=np.linspace(eMin,eMax,pts).flatten()
```

which solves the above error.

Output:

```
>>> minimize(test, 0.5, (10,1000))
      fun: 0.06741138275083512
 hess_inv: array([[2.84420795e+08]])
      jac: array([-5.75464219e-06])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 70
      nit: 34
     njev: 35
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([11715.27509055])
```

Comment: Replace *list* by *np.ndarray* and I'd agree with you :).

Comment: Does exactly the job. Problem solved, thanks!

Comment: @joni Changed it now!